# understanding Garbage Collection in java, and how to prevent misuse of heap space

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I'm not that expert about GC, i'm trying to understand whether it makes a difference for the objects heap size to have variable assignments instead of direct injestion of values into collections.

I have in my program, many variables storing a String object, these are then to be injected into a Collection, i think the previous developer wrote it this way for readability, but after our database has grown, the garbage collector throws an exception due reaching out of memory.

To be more clear, here an example. 
Suppose i have this simple class

```
class Person{
 String name;
 public Person(String name){
   this.name=name;
 }
 public String getName(){
  return name;
 }
}
```

Now suppose i have to insert 1000 person names into a Collection, would the second version be more GC friendly then the first one?

```
//Version 1: assign to variables first, then inject to list
List<Person> persons=SomeTool.getPersons();//this fills the list with 1000 Person objcts
List<String> names=new ArrayList<String>();
for(Person person:persons){
  String name=person.getName();
  names.add(name);
 }

//Version 2, No variable assignment here, inject into the list from the method returned value directly
List<Person> persons=SomeTool.getPersons();//this fills the list with 1000 Person objcts
List<String> names=new ArrayList<String>();
for(Person person:persons){
  names.add(person.getName());
 }
```

Comment: I strongly believe the bytecodes will be quite the same

Comment: In your example, nothing is ready for garbage collection, the heap allocation is exactly the same whether or not you have the `name` helper variable.

Comment: "more GC friendly" what do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not how the objects are inserted, the problem is that the objects are still in use while in the collection.

This means, if you add a person to the collection he becomes an object in use. If the person then became obsolete and no longer needed but kept in the collection he will still be in use and the garbage collector won't be able to destroy him. If you removed this person from the collection however as he became obsolete then he would be collected by the garbage collector